# Fat Free Framework PHP Sql statement with in expression

Tags: php, sql, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to include a list of strings to be used in an "in" expression in a sql statement for example:

```
select * from poop where id in ('asd','sas','ser')
```

I want to pass the in parameter from a variable. The quoting is really screwing me up. Should I be passing this as a string which I have been trying to no avail by making a comma seperated string that looks like this:

```
282366381A,240506808A,244154247A,491404349A,242443808B,328409296A,239723812A,383423679M
```

or `"282366381A","240506808A","244154247A","491404349A","242443808B","328409296A"`

or 
`'282366381A','240506808A','244154247A','491404349A','242443808B','328409296A'`

None of these work or is there a different way using an array of values?

This is the statement I'm using with the string:

```
$cernerResults = $this->cernerdb->exec( "select
        pat as HICN,
    from pat
    where
        HICN in ( ? )", $hicsString );
```

**Edit:**

I was able to get around this by constructing the entire query as a string like this:

```
$query = "select pat as HICN from pat where HICN in (".$hicsString.")";
```

$hicsString has single quotes around each item like so:

`'282366381A','240506808A','244154247A','491404349A','242443808B','328409296A'`

The problem is that providing the string to the exec would result in no results. When looking at the freetds log file the in expression values would be double quoted as a whole or each one would be double single quoted and if i used no quotes they would not be quoted at all.

All of these would make the statement return no results. I should also mention that this is a Sybase database.

Comment: its should be like this `'282366381A','240506808A','244154247A','491404349A','242443808B','328409296A'` Can u show the raw query built and give your exact problem

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem may come from the fact that PDO parser needs to have one value per question mark so it is able to validate it. So your "hack" with one question mark which is assigned to more than one value is where it fails IMHO.

This is how I handle case like that:

```php
$values = ['asd','sas','ser'];
$count = count($values);
$results = $db->exec(
    "select * from poop where id in ( ?".str_repeat(", ?", $count-1).")",
    $values
);
```

In general I would advice you using [data mappers](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.5/databases#CRUD(ButWithaLotofStyle)) instead of running the queries on a DB object. It is easier to iterate through them and it is more secure.

Comment: I am running queries because the sql statement is a join between several tables. is it possible to use the data mapper in this scenario. I could find no examples of this.

Comment: It is possible, but messy and therefore I wouldn't go that road. The best choice: go with the views. Pros are described on [F3 page](https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/databases#ProsandCons). If reasonable you can also keep some data from the second table in the first one and treat the second as a source data only. Last option: extend your SQL mapper and add some SQL vanila code there. At least this way you will have all the SQL code in one class only.

Comment: Unfortunately I only have read access to this database so no dice on creating views. thanks again for the advice!