# Is there a way of sanitize an array for an IN condition on PHP Fat Free Framework?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

For example, if I want to sanitize a string, I use the following code

```
$db->exec("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email", [':email' => 'john.smith@gmail.com']);
```

But if I want to use a IN condition the following code does not work

```
$db->exec("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email IN :emails", [':emails' => ['john.smith@gmail.com', 'juan.perez@gmail.com']]);
```

what is the proper way to do this? 
Thanks for your time

Comment: useful article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172114/fat-free-framework-php-sql-statement-with-in-expression

Comment: I saw that article, but I was looking for something less "manual", if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not easy way to do it, as the [PDO class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) itself doesn't provide any mechanism for it.

Here's how to do it:

```php
$emails = ['john.smith@gmail.com', 'juan.perez@gmail.com'];

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email IN (' .
       implode(',', array_fill(0, count($emails), '?')) . ')';
$i = 1;
$args = [];
foreach ($emails as $email)
  $args[$i++] = $email;

$db->exec($sql, $args);
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually, I didn't see [george007's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41180713/2588746), which is much more concise than mine. I didn't know that the framework automatically corrects any 0-indexed arguments array (PDO requires index to start at 1).

So here's the most concise you can get:

```
$emails = ['john.smith@gmail.com', 'juan.perez@gmail.com'];

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email IN (?' . str_repeat(',?', count($emails)-1) . ')';

$db->exec($sql, $emails);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I come from Laravel and I am maintaining some old projects in fat free and I feel that I returned to the stone age.

Comment: You can use a datamapper to make your easier. The f3-cortex mapper has support for arrays an IN fields built in.. i.e. `$results = $users->find(['email IN ?',$emails]);`